# Question regarding Lipschitz condition $\| f_1 - f_2 \| \leq k \|x_1 - x_2\|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Consider global Lipschitz condition:

$\| f(x_1) - f(x_2) \| \leq k \|x_1 - x_2\|$

We can manipulate it to:

$\frac{\| f(x_1) - f(x_2) \|}{\|x_1 - x_2\|} \leq k $

But according to the definition of a norm, is it legal to then say the above is equivalent to:
$\| \frac{f(x_1) - f(x_2) }{x_1 - x_2}\| \leq k $ ?

Which is equivalent to

$\| \frac{df}{dx}\| \leq k $ ?

Comment: The last inequality is not equivalent, but indeed if the derivative is bounded then your function will be Lipschitz, according to the mean value theorem.

Comment: Technical aside: Notice that $x_1-x_2$ could be a vector. But the last portion is true: If $f$ is differentiable on a convex domain, then $f'$ is bounded if and only if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.